# Getting the screensize taken by a ScrollView with dynamic size?

Tags: flutter

I a pretty sure this question have been asked already but I have been looking for about 1 hour now and can't find the answer. So, if you do find relevant past questions, please do link.

I have a CustomScrollView that I use to create an infinite vertical list (endless scrolling behavior).

Inside this CustomScrollView, I have custom widget cards that load dynamically and in an infinite manner, that I want to be the size that the CustomScrollView take on the screen (not the size of the screen though, see the picture below, basically I want a way to have the size of the white arrow on the right side).

Graphic representation:

[image]

I am currently hard coding the size but in my real usage, the size of the appbar above can change dynamically so that's not a possibility in the future.

What's the way to provide this value to my cards?

Here are the only answers I could find so far:

- double.infinity: but this obviously will not work since the cards will just try to expend to an infinite height
- MediaQuery.sizeOf(Context) Is what I use currently while hard-coding, I substract it with the constant size of my bar, but this won't work in the future as already explained above

Comment: I never used it but maybe it's what you are looking for https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverLayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: @pskink LayoutBuilder seems to work for now but I'm pretty sure your suggestion is the actual answer when I am actually starting to make the appbar behave the way I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `LayoutBuilder` widget which provides parent widget constraints (*width and height of the parent*). and you can allocate as big as the parent widget does.

Try

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dynamic Demo'),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(index*50, index*20, index*10, 1),
              ),
              itemCount: 20,
            );
          },
        ));
  }
```

The container allocate the remaining space of the screen, you can apply that on the card.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for.